# compare between two file and extract the difference between them to other file bash

Tags: bash

i have two files have

data-home
data-backup

i want to compare between them and extract the difference to other file

that is my basic code to get the data and sort it

```
#!/bin/bash
sour=/home/server1/
dest=/home/server1/Downloads/

echo "List source files:" $sour
ls  | du -sh $sour* | awk -F "/" '{print $1,$NF}' | tee home-size 
echo "List destnation files:" $dest
ls  | du -sh $dest* | grep -v "107" | awk -F "/" '{print $1,$NF}' |tee 
backup-size 

echo "calculate difference"
diff home-size backup-size
```

Comment: What is wrong exactly with your current code ?

Comment: FYI, pasting your code in [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) shows a bad usage of the command `du`. Maybe your problem is related to this ?

Comment: there is no wrong just i want to extract the diff to other file only the diff

Comment: Is it about how to make file redirection ? something like `diff home-size backup-size > out.file` ?

Comment: Why are you piping `ls` to `du` *and* specifying a glob to `du`?!

Answer (score 0):

You could use bsdiff and bspatch.
To make the patchfile, it does a binary diff between the two first args.

```
bsdiff data-home data-backup patchfile
```

You can then apply it using bspatch. This takes the file and recombines it with the patch to make the reconstituted "new" file.

```
bspatch data-home newly-generated-data-backup patchfile
```